# how to convert datetime to string and make it in a datetimepicker

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker, tostring, dtr

I created a Search in vb.net button that allows me to display the elements of my table 'book' with as properties (code_ouvrage,id, title book, publishing house and date of edition) now I would like that when I do the search that the value of date of edition (which is of type date format 0000/00/00 is displayed in the `DateTimePicker1`. I already tried this:

```
DateTimePicker1.Value = dtr("date").ToString
```

I was waiting for him to return the date value in my MySQL database that he will display in the `DateTimePicker`.

Comment: What is `dtr`, a `DataRow`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand the question right. But if you want to put date value to datetimepicker, you can do something like that:

```
If Not IsDBNull(dtr("date")) Then
   DateTimePicker1.Value = CDate(dtr("date"))
End If
```

I hope it was helpful.

EDITED:

As you asked me, you also need to check if the date is Nothing:

```
If Not IsDBNull(dtr("date")) AndAlso dtr("date") IsNot Nothing Then
    DateTimePicker1.Value = CDate(dtr("date"))
End If
```

Checking if date `Is Nothing` Is equivalent to check if a Date is `Date.MinValue`. The value `01/01/0001 00:00:00`is the minimum value of Date.

Comment: i do it and get this  error   :   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : 'La valeur '01/01/0001 00:00:00' n'est pas valide pour 'Value'. 'Value' doit être compris entre 'MinDate' et 'MaxDate'.
Nom du paramètre : Value'

Comment: Sorry @CheikhDiallo I forget to check if the date is Nothing (in VB is equivalent to Date.MinValue). I have modified the answer to solve this.